# Precise Definition of 1-out-of-2 Oblivious Transfer

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography, security-definition, oblivious-transfer

What's the precise definition for 1-out-of-2 OT? and what's the best way to show that it can't be achieved under unconditionally secure setting?

I am reading about it and just couldn't get my head around it as there's a lot of different OT.

Thanks